# How to use gglocator without specifying number of clicks in advance?

Tags: r, ggmap

Using `gglocator()` like that defaults to one click.

Is it possible to use `ggloactor` such that it deals with the **dynamic** number of clicks? i.e. User should be free to click as many number of times he wants.

?

Comment: How is the system supposed to break out of waiting for the next click?

Comment: @DWin I understand that, but is there some other solution? Some other API for the same?

Comment: The code is available. You can rewrite it with a repeat-until loop that checks to see of the click is outside the plot area.

Comment: @DWin Can you point me to the code link, please?

Comment: In R most of the time all you need to do to see the code is type the unquoted name of the function at the console. If that doesn't work then just put the unquoted named inside `getAnywhere()`. This _should_ have been part of the "Introduction to R". You might want to run through your introductory materials again.

Comment: @DWin Thanks DWin, I'll look into the code the way you have said.